# SQL - join multiple tables using 2 references

Tags: sql, powerquery

I'm trying to join 7 tables .
5 out of the 7 tables I can link via the same reference (part number)
The last 2 tables I can use a reference (GL code) that will link it to 2 of the 5 tables.

Here's the code I used but I don't think it's right.  Is there a better way of writing this?

```
SELECT 
CODE.A30 as GL_CODE_DESCRIPTION,
STKAS.BC1PART as PART_NUM,
STKMM.AVDES1 as MAN_DESC,
STKMP.AWDES1 as PUR_DESC,
STKAS.BC1QTYH as INVENTORY,
ICSTM.CGSTCS as MAN_STD_COST,
ICSTP.CHSTCS as PUR_STD_COST,


FROM STKAS
LEFT JOIN STKMM ON STKMM.AVPART = STKAS.BC1PART
LEFT JOIN STKMP ON STKMP.AWPART = STKAS.BC1PART
LEFT JOIN ICSTM ON ICSTM.CGPART = STKAS.BC1PART
LEFT JOIN ICSTP ON ICSTP.CHPART = STKAS.BC1PART,
CODE

WHERE
STKMM.AVGLED = CODE.A9
OR
STKMP.AWGLED = CODE.A9
```

Comment: I see 6 tables. It would help to have more detail about the relationships.  Are you attempting to join a separate row in `CODE` with each of `AVGLED` and `AWGLED`?  The `or` logic could be fine.  But you should still use the `JOIN / ON` form for that. Something like: `LEFT JOIN CODE ON CODE.A9 IN (STKMM.AVGLED, STKMP.AWGLED)` .. Whether you really want outer joins or not is unknown with the detail provided.  If you want two separate codes in the same result row, you will need 2 corresponding joins, not just the one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply John, so the SKAS table has the inventory balance by SKU#, the STKMM and STKMP have the SKU descriptions by type (STKMM = manufactured items, STKMP = purchased items).  STKMM and STKMP also has the GL codes per SKU.  ICSTP and ICSTM has the standard costs again by item type (manufactured vs purchased).  What I want to add is the GL Code description which is in the CODE table.  I can only relate it to STKMM and STKMP and not the others.